# How to make a callgraph for a dll?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2012, profiler, call-graph

I have a native C/C++ x64 dll that I want to profile for static code analysis.

In Linux I do this step in my workflow with callgrind/valgrind and KCachegrind.

I want to do something like this for a Windows dll.

Unfortunately, I am not able to instrument the dll for step-by-step debugging in VS (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086693/how-to-setup-debugging-for-a-native-dll-in-a-c-sharp-project).

Does anybody know of any tools that can aid in the generation of a callgraph for a Windows dll called from a C# gui in a way that is independent of the C# caller program?

**edit**

I want to make a chart similiar to this: http://python.rk.edu.pl/site_media/resources/python.rk.edu.pl/images/djangoprof2.png

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to accomplish, a detailed list of what functions were called and the parameter information that was passed to them?

Comment: @johnathon I want to make a chart where I can see which functions are called by which functions. See the edit. Parameter passing information and profiling is a plus.

Comment: so you want a call stack. WinDbg.

Comment: or, just use the profiler... in visual studio. There is a way to get vs to make a nice pretty map of it, it was featured on channel9 a while back, but alas, i don't have 2012 available to me atm.

Comment: @johnathon I can't run the profiler because my caller C# code doesn't recognize the dll as anything more than a dll (subject of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086693/how-to-setup-debugging-for-a-native-dll-in-a-c-sharp-project). I have 2 projects and I need to instrument the dll independent of the C# gui.

Comment: @jonhathon: A call stack is the path of functions taken to the current point in execution. A call graph is a graph that shows all possible paths through the code, and doesn't necessarily require you to execute it.

Comment: Can you get a link map of the dll?